# How to get the added object from snapshotChanges() or valueChanges()?

Tags: ionic-framework, observable, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am attempting to fire local notifications based on items added in a current snapshotChanges read, but I don't want the entire array of objects, I just want the latest added object.

```
constructor( public afs: AngularFirestore ) {
    // Monitor all activities
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('activity', x => x.orderBy('saved', 'desc'));
    this.items$ = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data();
        const id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
}
```

It's my hope that I can take action every time a new item is added, only on that particular new item.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following:

```
// Listen to the observable for changes, take the first item of that array.
this.items$.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```